# Requirements to build a poisontap

Tags: networking, pi-3, hardware, ethernet, security

I'm new to single board computing and to hardware. I've found PoisonTap to be an interesting project, tough I've got no idea where to start. What would be a list of concepts I'd need to know in order to setup a PoisonTap(not how to use it)?

I'm interested in using a Pi 3, since that's what I have. Pi zero is harder to get by nowadays.

https://samy.pl/poisontap/

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=166010) this can only be run on a Pi Zero because of a certain feature that is only on that board:

> No, because it relies on flipping the Pi Zero's SoC single direct usb
>   port interface from host to a client (aka gadget mode). The Pi 2/3
>   have an onboard usb hub between the SoC and the usb ports, so even if
>   you flipped it to client mode the hub is in the way.

As far as concepts I believe this would not be in the scope of the Raspberry Pi SE but it looks like you don't have to know much in order to make it since the author provides all the code on [github](https://github.com/samyk/poisontap). You would however need to know how to exploit the computer after the "PoisonTrap" made the backdoor.

Comment: Thanks. It's written on Samy's website that you can do it with an Ethernet to usb dongle. The code on github only works for the Pi zero setup. My question regarding concepts only refers to the setup.